# How to solve type missmatch in scala

Tags: scala, types, tree, fold

i need some help with this code in scala, i want to implement foldL method but im getting this:

```
asd.scala:73: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[MyTree[A]] => B
 required: B
      def myFoldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = (_:Option[MyTree[A]]) match {
                                                                          ^
one error found
```

I know thats a type missmatch but im newbie with scala and Oriented Object and i dont 
understand how to solve this situation.

```
class MyTree[A](val value: A, val left:Option[MyTree[A]],
                              val right:Option[MyTree[A]]) {

  def myFoldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = (_:Option[MyTree[A]]) match {
    case Some(tree) => right.get.myFoldLeft (left.get.myFoldLeft (op(z, value)) (op)) (op)
    case None => z
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `myFoldLeft` is returning a **Function** `Option[MyTree[A]] => B` instead of the `B` you say it will return. The reason is this: `(_:Option[MyTree[A]])` that underscore extends to `(x :Option[MyTree[A]]) => x match`. I believe what you want is just `this.match` but then, it is not and **Option**. You may want to rethink your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(_:Option[MyTree[A]]) ...` is a lambda.

You should match like

```
class MyTree[A](val value: A, val left:Option[MyTree[A]],
                val right:Option[MyTree[A]]) {    
  def myFoldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = (left, right) match {
    case (Some(left), Some(right)) => ???
    case (Some(left), None) => ???
    case (None, Some(right)) => ???
    case (None, None) => ???
  }
}
```